# Add a group in SQL 2008 RC

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a group called `kwr-fs-dws-sqladm` (Active Directory/Exchange) and there are two users in this group.

This group will go to all sql server and instances. I have access to windows server 2008 as admin.

How can I add that group in all 60 SQL Servers and 200 Instances?

i.e. kwr-fs-dws-sqladm - user as sysadmin -.

Answer (score 0):

```
Use [Master]
CREATE LOGIN [DOMAIN\kwr-fs-fws-sqladm] FROM WINDOWS; 
EXEC sp_addsrvrolemember 'DOMAIN\kwr-fs-fws-sqladm', 'sysadmin';
```

Execute on each server, you will want to check out the `CREATE LOGIN` syntax for extra options.

I've never managed that many SQL servers, i'd assume there is a way of executing on all. One way is to add each server to a server group in SSMS, then you can right click that group and create a new query which will execute on each server.

Comment: U mean, i have to login all windows server + all 60 sql server and 200 instances to a group to access the sql server. There must be so way to add that group as user for sql. And in that group there are 2 user can able to login SEPERATE. Thanks even though. its me a lot of sense

Comment: Servers don't matter, you have to connect to all 200 instances and add the domain group as a login for that sql instance, then add it to the sysadmin role.